# RegularExpression validation in .NET Core

Tags: regex, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to validate the input to an API controller via RegulardExpression annotation in the model class. It is working well when I enter a string input as a value for the attribute. However, the problem I have is that it does not return an error for an empty string, so in the cases when the attribute value is an empty string the validation does not return an error.

Here is the example of the model class and the annotation I have:

```
    public class TestClass
{
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]{7}$")]
    public string TestField{ get; set; }
}
```

And the controller method looks like this:

```
[Route("update/test")]
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateObject(TestClass test)
    {
        .........
    }
```

Can you please tell me how can I set the regex so that it recognises that an empty string is not a valid input?

UPDATE: 
Adding [MinLength(1)] attribute to my class field allowed me to disable entering empty strings as input for the field.

Comment: Make it a required field, add `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your error message.")]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, wouldn't then I always be forced to add the value of the field? Because this is not want I want to achieve, the attribute can be omitted but if the value is entered then it always has to match the regex.

Comment: But your regex, `^1[0-9]{7}$`, does not match an empty string. So, it is already working as expected.

Comment: That is also why I am surprised by the fact that it is accepting the empty string as a correct value

Comment: There is a chance it is not working due to absence of the error message, try adding it, `[RegularExpression(@"^1[0-9]{7}$", ErrorMessage = "Must start with '1' and then have any seven digits.")]`

Comment: Why not just use `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]` ?

Comment: Hi @nwpie, thank you for your suggestion, however that would also imply that I always need to specify the attribute which is not something I want in my app,

Answer (score 2):

From MS Docs:

> If the value of the property is null or an empty string (""), the value automatically passes validation for the RegularExpressionAttribute attribute. To validate that the value is not null or an empty string, use the RequiredAttribute attribute.

See [RegularExpressionAttribute Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

So as mentioned in the comment, you need to add `Required` attribute as well.